# Error in installing QGIS 2.6 using Osgeo in Windows 8.1

Tags: installation, windows-8, qgis-2.6

I was trying to load QGIS 2.6 on Windows 8.1 using OsGeo installer. Though the files are loading fine while launching the software it is showing a series of errors. Some on these are -

1. The procedure entry point xmlShemaNewDocParserCtxt could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\OSGeo4W\bin\Spatialite4.dll
2. Package: Unknown package
   qgis-common.bat exit code -1073741515
   qgis-dev.bat exit code -1073741515
3. Package: Unknown package
   qgis-common.bat exit code -1073741511

I don't know how to get across these issues.

Answer (score 2):

I recently installed 2.6 on my win 8.1 laptop using the basic installer and it is the first install I have had in ages that starts up without error messages. So maybe try the basic installer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problems with windows xp. In particular the points 2) and 3).
The results is that the grass plugin doesn't work and GRASS too is enable to open the project or create a mapset.
The same happen using the stand alone installation (basic) of QGIS and GRASS.
I think it is a problem of windows, but I haven't still solved it.
You can have additional information on https://plus.google.com/102449423379632754833/posts/gWobkCozHCG.